# Highlight the value by using visual attributes of column after searching in oracle form in a button trigger

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

- Edited Version---

IN this oracle form i have fetched the data using cursor and i want to highlight  values which are starting from certain alphabet or word in column by  clicking on search button and I have used visual attribute block  and use this code in WHEN_BUTTON_PRESSED Trigger but it is not working .Did I used wrong trigger because on compiling there is no error but not executing on running

declare

```
     cursor emp_cur is
                select e.employee_id,e.last_name,e.salary,e.hire_date,e.department_id,d.department_name
                from employees e,departments d
                where e.department_id=d.department_id and e.department_id = :dept.deptid;
```

begin

```
        first_record;
   for i in emp_cur
            loop
        
         :emp.empid := i.employee_id;
         :emp.ename := i.last_name;
         :emp.sal := i.salary;
         :emp.hire_date := i.hire_date;
         :emp.deptid := i.department_id;
         :emp.dname := i.department_name;
    
            next_record;
            
                    
            end loop;
            end;
```

**created another button to search the highlighed value[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBgkm.png)**
go_block('emp');
begin

```
loop
    first_record;   
        if lower(:emp.ename) like :emp.txt_search||'%' then       
            set_item_instance_property('emp.ename',current_record,visual_attribute,'VA');
            else 
                    if :system.last_record = 'TRUE' THEN
                exit;
                    else next_record;
            end if;
        end if;
end loop;
go_item('txt_search');
```

end;

Comment: So, when you press that button, code you posted executes, populates block with data (fetched by the cursor) and *should* paint all ENAME fields with color set in the VA visual attribute, but - apparently - that doesn't happen. Which part of it doesn't happen? Do you get data you expected? Are there ENAMEs that start with a B (because, if not, IF-THEN won't happen)? Did you get *any* error while running the form? You said it compiles, but - is there a runtime error? Could you post a screenshot which shows that form?

Comment: I'd say that having the first_record inside the loop is probably an issue.  It's going to go back to the first record every time through the loop.  Also having the system.last_record check inside the first IF is a problem, because it will never get there unless the text does not match.